# C# need to get data from xml to verify login

Tags: c#, xml, forms, authentication

I'm trying to Create a login form, and registration form.
My registration form is complete,
by registrating an XML file is created with this code,

```
    private void newregisterBtn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (usernameTxb.Text == null && nameTxb.Text == null && ageTxb.Text == null && countryTxb.Text == null && passwordTxb.Text == null)
       {
            usernLbl.ForeColor = Color.Red;
            nameLbl.ForeColor = Color.Red;
            ageLbl.ForeColor = Color.Red;
            countryLbl.ForeColor = Color.Red;
            passwordLbl.ForeColor = Color.Red;
 // this doesn't work

        }
        else
        {
            string filename = @"C:\\testxml\\" + usernameTxb.Text + ".xml";

            XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
            XmlElement root = doc.CreateElement("Login");
            XmlElement id = doc.CreateElement("id");
            id.SetAttribute("userName", usernameTxb.Text);
            id.SetAttribute("passWord", passwordTxb.Text);
            XmlElement name = doc.CreateElement("Name");
            name.InnerText = nameTxb.Text; 
            XmlElement age = doc.CreateElement("Age");
            age.InnerText = ageTxb.Text;
            XmlElement Country = doc.CreateElement("Country");
            Country.InnerText = countryTxb.Text;
            id.AppendChild(name);
            id.AppendChild(age);
            id.AppendChild(Country);
            root.AppendChild(id);
            doc.AppendChild(root); 
            doc.Save(filename);
            MessageBox.Show("Created SuccesFully!");
            this.Close();

        }
    }
```

Now that's not to important, on my second form (login form), i just got an 'usernameTxb'  a 'passwordTxb' a 'loginBtn' and a 'registerBtn'.

Now i want a piece of code that finds and see if the usernameTxb and passwordTxb are equal to the info writen into the xml file.
here is some xml code.

```
<Login>
  <id userName="Username" passWord="password">
    <Name>Joshua Maerten</Name> 
    <Age>21</Age> 
    <Country>Belgium</Country> 
  </id>
</Login>
```

Comment: Excelent Post http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4683834/c-sharp-need-to-get-data-from-xml-to-verify-login/17239325#17239325

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you can use LINQ for XML parsing this should conceptually work based on your XML:

```
public static bool IsValidLogin(string user, string password)
{
    XDocument doc = XDocument.Load("Login.xml");

    return doc.Descendants("id")
              .Where(id => id.Attribute("userName").Value == user 
                     && id.Attribute("passWord").Value == password)
              .Any();
}
```

Comment: The problem is, the file is named after the usernameTxb, lik BrokenGlass.xml, by this string:"" string filename = @"C:\\testxml\\" + usernameTxb.Text + ".xml"; "". And when i place it before xDocument doc = new.... he says :  Error 1 An object reference is required for the non-static field, method, or property 'application.Login.usernameTx. I'm noob at this i helping my way true the internet, but can u give me code for the loginbutton.

Comment: just replace `"login.xml"` with `user +".xml"` then, why would you have a separate file for each user though? Just list them all in one overall file, your XML structure supports that already (the fact that you should never store login data in clear text as an aside)

Comment: I'm noob at this i helping my way true the internet, but can u give me code for the loginbutton.

Answer (score 2):

[image: Asp Login Page]

[image: XmlDocument]

[image: CodeBehindPage(.cs)]
Hi This Article For Who Are Suffering From Login Page Using Xml Document With Asp.net And C#.
Please see Below Details You Will Clarify All Details Thanks Yours Raffi.